# Gaussian Process, negative hyper-parameters?

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, hyperparameters

I'm doing Gaussian Processes for Regression using GPML toolbox. However, after optimization using 'minimize.m' (without mean functions), I get some negative hyper-parameters!

The initial hyper-parameters are:

`hyp.cov = [0; 0];  % two hyper-parameters in covariance kernel (length-scale & amplitute)
hyp.lik = log(0.1);   %hyper-parameters of noise`

The original training data:

```
x=[819 1119 1419 1599 1719 1839 1899 2019 2079 2139];   %coordinates

y=[105.00  114.33  126.33 130.33  116.33  103.00  103.00  124.67  122.67  109.00]; %training data
```

In my codes, y are **NORMALIZED** to have zero mean and unit variance. Then optimize:

```
hyp = minimize(hyp, @gp, -100, @infExact, [], {@covSEiso}, likfunc, x,y);
```

After about 100 iterations, I get some negative hyper-parameters!!! It is quite confusing....

However, if I don't normalize y, all hyper-parameters will be positive after optimization.

Could anyone tell me what does Negative Hyper-parameters mean?  Should I normalize the data?

Comment: The hyper-parameter is defined as `exp(log(\theta))`, so even if you get a negative hyper-parameter, by definition it is constrained to be positive.

Answer (score 0):

The mistake is that already the initial noise-parameter is negative:

```
hyp.lik = log(0.1);   %hyper-parameters of noise
```

So I'd suggset you use a positive noise-variance and try again.

Regarding your other question, yes, it is usually a good idea to normalize the data (i.e. give them zero-mean and unit-variance).

A possible reason why this behaviour occurs only for the centralized data might be that the variance becomes smaller than the variance of the original data. Remember that in Bayesian Linear Regression (--what Gaussian Processes in principle are), the noise variance is simply added to the covariance matrix. In your case, this addend is negative, and its effect is of course larger for smaller variance.

Answer (score -1):

Hyperparameters in the GPML toolbox are represented as logarithms. So if you want to get the actual length-scale value, perform exp(X) on the vector.